# post not finding php file on local server.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xampp

I'm trying to use an post call to a get some data from a php file.  I know the code works because I'm using it on another computer and it works fine.  Every time I make a call I get this error.

```
 HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost/PhpProject4/‪newEmptyPHP.php
```

This is from MS edge.  The php file is in the same directory as the html file and the file making the call.  I think it has to do with my xampp server.  Any Ideas?  Also this is all on my local machine.

Comment: Have you try in Private window?

Comment: same, nothing still getting the same message

Answer (score 0):

Just check your .htaccess file, maybe mod_rewrite changes adress